# How to avoid multiple JOINS on the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Two tables exist, for example:

```
GROUPS
id team1_id team2_id
1     1       2
2     3       1

TEAMS
id  name
1   aaa
2   bbb
3   ccc
```

I need to obtain the team names in the group.  So, the query looks like this and it works but it's relatively slow because of the multiple joins for the Team table.

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name
FROM Groups g
JOIN Teams t1 ON t1.id = g.team1_id 
JOIN Teams t2 ON t2.id = g.team2_id
```

Is it possible to avoid the multiple join without changing schema or must the schema change to improve this?  There will only ever be 2 teams per group.

Comment: Can't really see any way around this, do you have an index on `Teams{Id, Name}` (if you have more columns in the TEAMS table)?

Comment: ID is the PK. There is no index on Name though.  why would that help?

Comment: No it doesnt work slow because of multiple JOINs.Look for indices,or better configre Mysql.

Comment: What do you mean by look for indicies?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: If you have more columns in the TEAM table an index with only id and name will be smaller to read from disk / fit in RAM than the whole table and thus it will be faster.

Comment: What do you mean "relatively slow"?  You query is fine and with primary keys it should go quite fast.  How much data do you have?

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo Please keep in mind that InnoDB tables are [clustered](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/), which (among other things) means that the primary index automatically [covers](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) all the fields.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo While it's technically true that index on {id, name} could be "narrower" than index on {id, ...everything...} that you effectively get with clustering, I doubt it would have much impact on performance of this particular query unless we are talking about huge amounts of data and very wide rows (not shown above). And of course, every additional index brings extra cost of its own...

Comment: Show your table definitions. (Since that affects performance.)

Answer (score 0):

You could see if this performs any better - (uses one join, but a union on that table)

```
select x.id, group_concat(t.name order by x.id) as team_names
  from (select id, team1_id as team_id
          from groups
        union all
        select id, team2_id
          from groups) x
  join teams t
    on x.team_id = t.id
 group by x.id
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ba95c/4/0

Or if you absolutely need to have each team in a separate column:

```
select id,
       substring_index(team_names, ',', -1) as team1,
       substring_index(team_names, ',', 1) as team2
  from (select x.id, group_concat(t.name order by x.id) as team_names
          from (select id, team1_id as team_id
                  from groups
                union all
                select id, team2_id
                  from groups) x
          join teams t
            on x.team_id = t.id
         group by x.id) x
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ba95c/10/0

Answer (score 0):

you can use two join per two id like this:

```
SELECT id1, name1, name2 FROM 
  (SELECT Groups.id AS id1, Groups.team1_id as tid1, Teams.name as name1  FROM Groups LEFT JOIN Teams ON Groups.team1_id = Teams.id) AS S1,
  (SELECT Groups.id AS id2, Groups.team2_id as tid2, Teams.name as name2  FROM Groups LEFT JOIN Teams ON Groups.team2_id = Teams.id) AS S2
  WHERE id1=id2
  ORDER BY id1
```

Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2952af/2